# Keyboard shortcut for Sort By Date Created

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

As there’s not one built-in (see hold <kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd> and navigate to Finder->View->Sort By), I tried to create a custom keyboard shortcut for **Sort By Date Created** in Finder (such as the built-in for **Sort By Name** <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd><kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd><kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>).

However, whichever keyboard combination I assign to it doesn’t work (i.e. <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd><kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd><kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>, or <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd><kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd><kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>, etc.)

How can I create a custom keyboard shortcut for **Sort By Date Created**?

Comment: Default shortcut is `⌃`+`⌥`+`⌘`+`5` (CTRL+ALT+CMD+5) to Sort By Date (not ALT+SHIFT+RETURN+5).

Comment: That’s what I meant/used, but made a mistake when posting the question — I edited the message. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, default shortcut ⌃⌥⌘5 is for Sort By Date Modified.

Comment: It Seems that what ever you try the call is going to `Arrange by` Date Created rahter the `Sort by` Date Created That is even where my shortcut shows up

Comment: @markhunte No, it isn’t it’s exactly *Sort By Date Created*, the one that shows up instead of *Arrange* when you go to *View* and hold <kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd> key.

Comment: @SinišaŠašić Yes. I know what you are after. What I am saying is when I tested this. The short cuts are showing up in the Arrange menu's Date Created but not the Sort by's Date Created. Therefore the Arrange by gets called instead.

Comment: @markhunte in any case it doesn’t assign the shortcut as it should. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that date created is a visible column in list view in finder. You can do this by entering list view and right clicking the headers and checking date created.

Then go to system preferences, keyboard, Shortcuts, and choose app shortcuts on the left. Then add a new shortcut for Finder by pressing the plus button and choosing finder from the drop down. In the menu title put "Date Created" exactly (without the quotes). Then focus the shortcut field and press your desired shortcut. For example Option+Command+8

Tested it in Mavericks and it works for me.

Comment: You sure your not getting Arranged by Date Created.. Because I have don this on two Macs earlier today and that is the only Menu that picks up the shortcut

Comment: @Camden Narzt It works but it makes another problem — the shortcut is assigned both for *Arrange By* and *Sort By* so it’s totally confusing. I want to have different shortcuts for *Sort By Date Created* and *Arrange By Date Created*, which in your example is the same (as you can see in the Arrange and Sort menus to the right of the text).

Comment: It does set the shortcut for both actions, I don't think there's anything that can be done about that without installing additional software.